# Python flask and opening/using a file

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a web app that reads a selected file into the program and does calculations on the data inputted.

index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <hr/>
        <div>

            <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file"><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

python file

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        text_file = open(filename,"r")
        Data = text_file.read()
        return render_template('base.html',filename=filename)
```

Here I'm getting the file then saving it locally then opening it and getting the data. I want to get the "Data" into other functions to do calculations on. How do I go about getting my data to other functions?

I would like to have a page saying X file was loaded in then be able to click the tabs on my web app to run the calculations on said file.

Comment: save the data in database and fetch wherever you need

Comment: That makes the most sense i guess. Wasn't really thinking about adding a database but if that is the easiest/quickest way I will add a database. Thanks